# Toggle Display State with Button and Media Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for the best way to have display state that can be toggled via a button on the page, but that can also be overridden based on a media query. On large screens I want to default to a `horiz` layout, and provide the choice to toggle a `vert` layout instead. On smaller screens, I want to default to the `vert` layout and not allow the toggle.

My current solution relies on cascading to override styles in the stylesheet which I would like to avoid since it requires my styles to be in a specific order.

HTML:

Apply a default layout of `layout--horiz`. `layout` is also applied in order to override the specific layouts with `@media` queries.

```
<div id='layout' class='layout layout--horiz'>
  <a href="#" id='btn'>Toggle</a>
  <p>This</p>
  <p>is</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

In the `@media` query for small screens: hide the toggle, and hardcode the `vert` styles to the `layout` style to override the `layout--horiz` if applied.

```
#btn {
  display: block;
}

.layout--horiz p {
  display: inline;
}
.layout--vert p {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #btn {
    display: none;
  }

  .layout p {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

JS:

Toggle the specific `--horiz` and `--vert` classes on button click.

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#layout').toggleClass('layout--vert layout--horiz');
});
```

This solution works decently, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Note: Here is a [codepen to play with](http://codepen.io/fortruce/pen/wBbxBq).

Comment: You appear to have mistaken Stack Overflow for a Code Review site.

Comment: @forTruce If you would like to improve working code, you may delete it from Stack Overflow and instead post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am not asking for a code review. I provided a working solution to demonstrate that I have tried to solve the problem, but, as I stated, my solution is a hack relying on overriding styles later on in the stylesheet. I am seeking other methods entirely, not a review of my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution isn't far from optimal barring inclusion of your JS into a frontend framework. This is probably why you're receiving comments directing you to code review. To improve your solution use only one selector for state change. This will invoke two states to your layout `layout--horiz` and a default state. It's easy to make this change once you switch your media query to select for large displays instead of small ones.

HTML:

```
<div id='layout' class='layout layout--horiz'>
  <a href="#" id='btn'>Toggle</a>
  <p>This</p>
  <p>is</p>
  <p>a</p>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#btn {
  display: none;
}

.layout p {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
  #btn {
    display: block;
  }

  .layout.layout--horiz p {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

JS:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  $('#layout').toggleClass('layout--horiz');
});
```

Comment: This works well with only 2 displays states to toggle between. I also added a debounced callback on `window.resize` to automatically add/remove `layout--horiz` when the window is resized. Additionally, I added a sentinel class `layout--vert` in the javascript with no associated css to use to indicate if the user specifically chose a vertical layout even at the larger screen size. This way I can preserve that preference even through resizes.

Comment: @forTruce I thought you wanted the layout toggled by `#btn`, not `window.resize`. Your new solution sounds overly complicated for the intention of what you're building.

Comment: You're right! I had some css leftover in my non-trivial problem that made it seem like I needed the `window.resize`. After a second look I am able to remove the `window.resize`, and have a simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way of doing this could possibly be to have two separate style sheets one with horizontal layout and the other with vertical layout and then you can switch the style sheets on click function to get the preferred layout. Here is a link to something I found really quick.

https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Change-Style-Sheet-Using-Tutorial-CSS-Swap-Stylesheet

Comment: Using additional stylesheets would require the browser to request extra pages, and it also does not allow me to enact those same style changes through @media queries.